# Right tail of log-concave densities.

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Consider any density $g$ with support $(a,b)$ and $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$.

Is it possible to have $g$ log-concave on $(a,b)$ even if $\lim_{q\uparrow b}g(q)=+\infty$?

An ([1995](https://econwpa.ub.uni-muenchen.de/econ-wp/game/papers/9611/9611002.pdf), [1998](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022053198924000)) proves that the right tail of a log-concave density is at most exponential, but the proof seems to assume $(a,b)=\mathbb{R}$. It should hold for, say, $(a,b)=(0,1)$, right?

Comment: What is $q$ in the limit?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. $g(q)$ is density over $(a,b)$, both $a$ and $b$ finite.

Answer (score 1):

If$a,b$ are finite then random variables distributed according to $g$ are bounded. Bounded random variables are subgaussian. Subgaussian random variables are subexponential. So then using the claim cited in your question, yes it is possible.

Comment: But aren't log-concave densities light-tailed?

Comment: Why dont you consider Subgaussian light tailed?

Comment: Boundedness is about as light tailed as you can get :)

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing concepts here. Subexponential distributions would not imply heavier tails than exponential ones? Regarding boundedness, take for instance a Beta distribution over $(0,1)$. For some parameter values, $g$ can diverge to infinity as $q$ approaches $1$, right?